# Angular: How to kinda refresh the ngOnInit method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a sidebar with different redirects of specific products categories, when these buttons are clicked it redirects to a component that gets the URL params and makes a consult to service and retrieves the data of that specific category, the thing is, when a click it the first time, it works, but the second time it does not, it only changes the URL but does not refresh the data

sidebar.component.html

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a [routerLink]="['products/category']" [queryParams]="{name:category.name}" class="list-group-item"
     *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.name}}</a>
</div>
```

And the component that makes the magic

```
export class ViewAllProductsByCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  searchCategory: any;
  products: Product;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private productsService: ProductsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
      this.searchCategory = res.name;
    });
    this.productsService.searchCategoryProducts(this.searchCategory).subscribe(res => {
      this.products = res;
      console.log(this.products);
    });
  }

}
```

So, how do I refresh the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified a bit john's answer, this is how I fixed it

```
 export class ViewAllProductsByCategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      searchCategory: any;
      products: Product;
      mySubscription: any;
    
      constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                  private productsService: ProductsService,
                  private router: Router,
      ) {
        this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
          return false;
        };
        this.mySubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.router.navigated = false;
          }
        });
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
          this.searchCategory = res.name;
          console.log(this.searchCategory);
        });
    
        this.productsService.searchCategoryProducts(this.searchCategory).subscribe(res => {
          this.products = res;
          console.log(this.products);
        });
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.mySubscription) {
          this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular by default doesn't re-initialize an already loaded component.

But there is a way to bypass that feature:

```
let newLocation = `/pathName/5110`;
 // override default re use strategy
 this.router
    .routeReuseStrategy
    .shouldReuseRoute = function () {
        return false;
 };
 this.router
   .navigateByUrl(newLocation)
   .then(
   (worked) => {
     // Works only because we hooked
     // routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute 
     // and explicitly told it don't reuse
     // route which forces a reload.
     // Otherwise; the url will change but new
     // data will not display!
   },
   (error) => {
    debugger;
    }
 );
```

Just set the .shouldReuseRoute function to return false, that way the component will reload.

Here's more detail on that topic.
https://dev.to/jwp/angular-s-naviation-challenges-20i2

You can also configure the router to reuse the route.